# Stored procedure to return an extra column with count of foreign id in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Firstly I am new to SQL, and I have trouble in setting up a simple stored procedure. I am learning SQL and need some help here.

Scenario:

- I have two tables, `Fruits` and `Oranges`
- `Fruits` has the following columns

  - fruitId
  - fruitSeason
- `Oranges` has the following columns

  - organgesId
  - fruitId
  - orangeName

I want to create a stored procedure to return all `Fruits` along with an extra column count, this count will be total number of fruits id in `Oranges`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC ProcName
AS 
  SELECT f.Id, f.fruitSeason, COUNT(g.fruitId) 'Total Fruits in Oranges'
  FROM @fruits f 
  LEFT JOIN @Oranges g ON g.fruitId = f.Id
  GROUP BY f.Id, f.fruitSeason
```

### [Here is a live demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81421)

Comment: there is nothing more I could have asked ! awesome !

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want this:

```
create procedure yourFruit
as
    select f.fruitid, 
        f.fruitSeason,
        o.cnt TotalFruitOranges
    from fruits f
    left join 
    (
        select count(*) cnt, fruitid
        from oranges
    ) o
        on f.fruitid = o.fruitid
GO
```